# Highchart loading animation not working when giving 'verticalAlign' for 'setTitle'

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, pie-chart, dotnethighcharts

I am building a pie chart with highchart. I need to set custom title for my pie chart. And I need to align it to the center of the pie chart. Everything works fine except the initial circle loading animation of pie chart. If I remove

```
verticalAlign: 'middle',
```

It will work. The problem is only in `highchart v7.1.1` . This animation is working fine in `Highchart v7.0.3`.

[This is my codepen link.](https://codepen.io/abdulhakkim/pen/PvBmmj)

Can any one please help me to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reported issue: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/10835

To workaround enable `floating` in title configuration object:

```
title: {
    floating: true
},
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9nywd2mx/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/title.floating